# Android: listview crashes

Tags: android, onitemclicklistener

I'm using android listview and its working perfectly fine. my implementation as below

```
ListView listview = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(MyIncidentActivity.this,
    R.layout.row_incident, R.id.label_incident, db_results));
```

Now I introduced onItemClickListener as below and application crashes for no reason.

```
listview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                    long arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });
```

logcat

```
08-12 14:44:40.105: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(14525): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-12 14:44:40.105: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(14525): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{a.b/a.b.MyIncidentActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-12 14:44:40.105: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(14525):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
08-12 14:44:40.105: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(14525):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
08-12 14:44:40.105: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(14525):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
08-12 14:44:40.105: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(14525):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
08-12 14:44:40.105: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(14525):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-12 14:44:40.105: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(14525):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
08-12 14:44:40.105: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(14525):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
08-12 14:44:40.105: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(14525):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-12 14:44:40.105: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(14525):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
08-12 14:44:40.105: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(14525):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
08-12 14:44:40.105: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(14525):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
08-12 14:44:40.105: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(14525):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-12 14:44:40.105: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(14525): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-12 14:44:40.105: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(14525):     at a.b.MyIncidentActivity.onCreate(MyIncidentActivity.java:50)
08-12 14:44:40.105: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(14525):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
08-12 14:44:40.105: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(14525):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
08-12 14:44:40.105: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(14525):     ... 11 more
```

Can someone help me find out the reason. I'm lost with this error. within same application same implementation works fine but don't know why its not working.

Comment: Post the line that throws the NPE please

Comment: what line of code do you have at line no 50.

Comment: what is setListAdapter();? and show line 50 of MyIncidentActivity.java

Comment: listview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() is wot I have in 50th line :(

Comment: Are you providing the correct id for listview

Comment: yes i'm using the correct one.

Comment: You are extending Activity or ListActivity?

Comment: I'm extending to ListActivity

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well from you code where you are using

```
setListAdapter(adapter);
```

indicates that you are using `ListActivity`, and while using `ListActivity` you get your list as follow:

```
listView = this.getListView();
```

or you can use

```
listView = this.findViewById(android.R.id.list);
```

and you are using

```
listView = this.findViewById(R.id.list);
```

which is wrong in case of `ListActivity`, and `ListView` cannot be found and results in `NullPointerException`.

Comment: aaaaaaaaaaa.. thank goddddd :) you saved my day.. how silly am I :)

Answer (score 0):

Try like this.

```
Public class ABCD implements OnItemClickListener{
          ListView listview;//class varible

           listview = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
           setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(MyIncidentActivity.this,
           R.layout.row_incident, R.id.label_incident, db_results));
           listview.setOnItemClickListener(this);

        @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```