# Android listview setOnItemClickListener

Tags: android

```
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_campaign_list);


        Campaign campaign_data[] = new Campaign[]
                {
                        new Campaign(R.drawable.hlbb, "MSIG HLBB PA Extra"),
                        new Campaign(R.drawable.hlbb, "MSIG HLBB SSP Plus")
                };
        CampaignAdapter adapter = new CampaignAdapter(this, R.layout.listview_header_row, campaign_data);
        listView1 = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        listView1.setAdapter(adapter);

        listView1.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                                    long id) {

                String item = ((TextView)view).getText().toString();

                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), item, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
        });
    }
```

I can run the code above without setonitemclicklistener function, when i add the setOnItemClickListener, it stopped working.What is the error?? I'm new in Android..Thx

Comment: add your logcat...!!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7038197/android-listview-crashes

Comment: print error stacktrace

Comment: `String item = ((TextView)view).getText().toString();` is probably causing a ClassCastException

Comment: Thx. Blackbelt... the statement causing ClassCastException..

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how is your CampaignAdapter code, but you are trying to cast the row view which you are inflating into TextView. You should use your adapter to access the item using the position of element:

```
CampaignAdapter adapter = new CampaignAdapter(this, R.layout.listview_header_row, campaign_data);
    listView1 = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    listView1.setAdapter(adapter);
    listView1.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                                long id) {
            Campaign item = (Campaign) adapter.getItem(position);
            // Now you can access to the campaing value that you want
            // For instance, item.getText()
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), item.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
```