# My listview is showing null after applying onItemClickListener

Tags: java, android

I applied OnItemClickListener and now it is giving me NPE. Before applying the listener it was working fine

Here is my code

```
package com.example.pc.jbossoutreachapp;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class repositories extends AppCompatActivity {

    private String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    private ProgressDialog ProgDialog;
    private ListView listview;

    private static String url = "https://api.github.com/orgs/JBossOutreach/repos";

    ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> RepoDetails;


    public void link(View view)
    {
        TextView text = findViewById(R.id.Repolink);
        String url = text.getText().toString();

        Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
        startActivity(browserIntent);

    }



    public void Contributors(View view)
    {
        listview = this.findViewById(android.R.id.list);
        listview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                    int position, long id) {
                TextView textView = view.findViewById(R.id.RepositoryName);
                String text = textView.getText().toString();
                Log.e("nameeeeee", "Name is  == "+text);

            }});
        String url1 = "https://api.github.com/repos/JBossOutreach/lead-management-android/contributors";
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, contributors.class);
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString("url", url1);
        intent.putExtras(bundle);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.repositories);

        RepoDetails = new ArrayList<>();

        listview = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);

        new GetContacts().execute();
    }


    private class GetContacts extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>
    {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();

            ProgDialog = new ProgressDialog(repositories.this);
            ProgDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
            ProgDialog.setCancelable(false);
            ProgDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {

            HttpHandler sh = new HttpHandler();

            String Json_String = sh.makeServiceCall(url);

            Log.e(TAG, "Response from url: " + Json_String);

            if(Json_String != null)
            {
                try
                {
                  JSONArray array = new JSONArray(Json_String);
                    for(int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++)
                    {
                        JSONObject ob = array.getJSONObject(i);

                        String name = ob.getString("name");

                        JSONObject owner = ob.getJSONObject("owner");
                        String link = owner.getString("html_url");

                        HashMap<String, String> contact = new HashMap<>();

                        contact.put("name", name);
                        contact.put("link", link+"/"+name);

                        RepoDetails.add(contact);
                    }
                }
                catch(final JSONException e)
                {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Json parsing error: " + e.getMessage());
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                    "Json Parsing error: " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();                        }
                    });
                }
            }

            else
            {
                Log.e(TAG, "Couldn't get Json from server");
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                "Couldn't get json from server ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                });
            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
            super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
            if(ProgDialog.isShowing())
            {
                ProgDialog.dismiss();
            }

            ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                    repositories.this, RepoDetails, R.layout.repo_list_item, new String[]
                    {"name", "link"}, new int[]{R.id.RepositoryName, R.id.Repolink});

            listview.setAdapter(adapter);
        }

    }

}
```

> And i checked this answer too but this does not solved my problem
>
> [Android: listview crashes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7038197/android-listview-crashes)

I know i am doing something very wrong. Please help!!

Update

Logcat:

```
 Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:385)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5678) 
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22667) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:836) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:103) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:203) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6293) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1065) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:926) 
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ListView.setOnItemClickListener(android.widget.AdapterView$OnItemClickListener)' on a null object reference
        at com.example.pc.jbossoutreachapp.repositories.Contributors(repositories.java:51)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:385) 
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5678) 
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22667) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:836) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:103) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:203) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6293) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1065) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:926)
```

Comment: Please post the crash log too.

Comment: whitout error log it would be like guessing by looking only at code.

Answer (score 1):

Just before setting `setOnItemClickListener`, I think make a typo in your id, you should probably need to replace your id `android.R.id.list` to `R.id.list`:

```
listview = this.findViewById(android.R.id.list);
```

Or simply just remove it as you have already assigned the `ListView` in `onCreate`.

Also it's safe to move this block of lines to `onCreate` instead, just in case if your method `Contribute` is being called prematurely:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.repositories);

    RepoDetails = new ArrayList<>();

    listview = this.findViewById(R.id.list);
    listview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            TextView textView = view.findViewById(R.id.RepositoryName);
            String text = textView.getText().toString();
            Log.e("nameeeeee", "Name is  == "+text);
        }
    });
// ...
```

Comment: oh wait, is this used in your layout xml `android:onClick="Contribute"`?

Comment: yup! does that matter?

Comment: @DujanaArar It sort of does, because the view hasn't completely inflated yet, that's why it failed to find your `ListView`, and threw NullPointerException when you tried to assign it afterwards. But that's okay, just move the `setOnItemClick` assignment to `onCreate`, and it should work. I've updated my answer.

Comment: should i share my github link??

Comment: That's okay, I gave you a wrong id, it should be `R.id.list`. Can you try it again please?

Comment: Now, it is not giving me NPE but i cannot get String text in log e

Comment: @DujanaAbrar So I can assume you can click on them? Sorry but you're gonna have to figure it out how to get to the log, I could only help you getting rid of NPE and assigning view correctly. Or show me if there's any error left.

Answer (score 0):

You are initializing listview two times. Also in Contributors method you are using "`android.R.id.list`", you should use "`R.id.list`".

Try this, Remove the initialization from Contributors method, and add `onItemClickListener` in `onCreate` instead of contributors method.

Answer (score 0):

From your code, the NPE is obviously related with that the `listview` is null. This means that your activity couldn't find the ListView with the id of `android.R.id.list`. You should double check your XML layout to be sure that there is a ListView with the id of `android.R.id.list`.

It should be something like the following.
`android:id="@android:id/list`

**EDIT:**

Here is how to fix the issue of item click not working. In ListView, when there are clickable elements in item view, click event is not working for item view itself. To fix this, you just need to add two lines of code to make them not focusable. And here is full code for your reference.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="5dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/RepositoryName"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="15dp"
        android:paddingBottom="8dp"
        android:textColor="@color/NameRepo" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Repolink"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:onClick="link"
        android:paddingBottom="8dp"
        android:textColor="@color/colorAccent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:onClick="Contributors"
        android:text="@string/Contributors" />


</LinearLayout>
```

You just need to update your layout file - `repo_list_item`. As you can see, I just added following two lines to TextView with id `Repolink` and Button with id `button2` and that's all.

```
android:focusable="false"
android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
```

PS: We should now use RecyclerView to implement a list in android app, not ListView anymore.

Comment: it is the same. when i am removing the onClickListener it works fine. Should i share the xml file also?

Comment: @DujanaAbrar Yes, please

Comment: @DujanaAbrar Hold on please. I don't see the code which calls the method `Contributors`. So you are using it in xml, right?

Comment: yup, may i give you my github link or should i post the whole code here?

Comment: @DujanaAbrar Whatever you prefer. You can post xml code here or give me the github link.

Comment: @DujanaAbrar Actually, I'm not sure how you could possibly get ListView object from two IDs - android.R.id.list and R.id.list. One of them might not be a valid one.

Comment: @DujanaAbrar okay, I've checked your code. It's not giving NPE, but OnItemClickListener is not working. I have updated my answer about how to fix the issue, so you can check it out.